# How do I remove unwanted white line artifacts from Kbl table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

When I have a black background for cells using kbl I get unwanted white artifacts between the gridlines and the cells ([Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWBoE.png)). There are also artifacts with gray and white backgrounds([photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkwf7.png)).This might not be possible to fix because of the conversion between LaTeX and PDF. Depending on the zoom level of the PDF these lines can appear vertically, horizontally, both, or not appear at all([Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbB0B.png)).

EDIT: Grzegorz suggested it was a viewer issue which it turned out to be.

I tried setting the entire table to black and then building off of it. That way if the white lines were from the pdf document itself they would be covered by a large black box.

Here's the original code:

```
kbl(data, align = rep("c", ncol(data))) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 4, latex_options = c("scale_down", "hold_position")) %>%
  column_spec(c(12,13), color = "white",background = "black", include_thead = TRUE, width = "1cm", bold = T) %>%
  # column_spec(c(10,11), color = "white", include_thead = TRUE, width = "1cm") %>%
  column_spec(c(4,6,8,10,14), background = "lightgray", include_thead = FALSE, width = ".6cm") %>%
  column_spec(c(5,7,9,11,15), background = "white", include_thead = FALSE, width = ".6cm")
```

Here's my latest attempt to fix it:

```
kbl(data, align = rep("c", ncol(data))) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 4, latex_options = c("scale_down", "hold_position")) %>%
  column_spec(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), background = "black", include_thead = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(c(12,13), color = "white",background = "black", include_thead = TRUE, width = "1cm", bold = T) %>%
  # column_spec(c(10,11), color = "white", include_thead = TRUE, width = "1cm") %>%
  column_spec(c(4,6,8,10,14), background = "lightgray", include_thead = FALSE, width = ".6cm") %>%
  column_spec(c(5,7,9,11,15), background = "white", include_thead = FALSE, width = ".6cm")  %>%
  column_spec(c(1,2,3), background = "white", include_thead = TRUE)
```

This is in an R Markdown file and here is the YAML for that:

```
---
title: |
 | ![](images/BrandImage.jpg){width=2in}
 | `r unlist(strsplit(params$fullname,split = '_'))[2]` Forecast
params:
  fullname: "placeholder"
  vendorNo: "placeholder"
output:
 pdf_document:
   latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Segoe UI
classoption: landscape
---
```

Libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tinytex)
library(glue)
library(knitr)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
```

Comment: As you noted: "Depending on the zoom level of the PDF these lines can appear vertically, horizontally, both, or not appear at all(Photo 3)." -- I would assume, those artifacts are caused by PDF viewer (Acrobat, Document Viewer or whatever you using) and are related to up-/down-scaling the graphics to monitor resolution. What happens if you print out the PDF on printer?

Comment: Great question! The behavior is identical between Chrome and Edge. However on Adobe Acrobat Reader there are no artifacts. Follow up - is there a way to increase the grid line thickness in Kable to your knowledge? I have looked through a ton of parameters and haven't found anything. If there's not Ill mark this as the answer. THANKS!

Comment: Hey, not sure if that's in kableExtra itself, or in latex template behind kableExtra -- haven't played with it for a while. Please have a look on https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf and for debugging please set up `keep_tex: true` option in output yaml header. It will allow you at least to find the place, where (and how) the tables are defined.